# Sharepoint - Company intranet document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, access

I'm setting up a document library for an organisation. Bearing in mind that certain folders should only be accessible (visible) by certain users (eg. Human resources staff), and some other folders should be accessible to some specified users, would it be better to create it as one document library or a set of distinct document libraries (eg. for HR, Finance, Delivery, etc.)?

Is it possible to have one document library and create a hierarchy of subfolders with distinct permissions for different user groups or users?

Please advise. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, it's not recommended to use hierarchy of subfolders to set different permissions for users.

You could create different folders in the library. Then grant these folders with different permissions for different users.

[image]

References:

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

[Change the permissions on a subfolder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427bd7c-f20a-4f75-8cf2-5359dd45a1a6)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm confused. How is my 'hierarchy of subfolders' different from 'different folders'. Both, as any folder structure, are really a hierarchy of (sub)folders. Unless, I've misunderstood your answer:)

Comment: I mean that you could create folders with same level, not hierarchy. Add picture in the answer.